# Is there a Java XML to JSON library to produce output JSON with no property where input XML has xsi:nil="true"

Tags: java, json, xml

Is there a Java XML to JSON library to produce output JSON with no property where input XML has xsi:nil="true"?

XML input example:

```
<root>
  <ele1>Has content</ele2>
  <ele2 xsi:nil="true" />
</root>
```

Expected JSON output

```
{
  "root":{
     "ele1":"Has content"
  }
}
```

My input is XML not a POJO. I want to see if there is a library that avoids e.g. using JAXB/Jackson.

Using json.org, I currently get e.g.:

```
{
  "root":{
     "ele1":"Has content",
     "ele2":[
        "xsi:nil":true
      ]
  }
}
```

I would prefer not to have null values in the JSON, but the properties not to be there. I.e. not:

```
{
  "root":{
     "ele1":"Has content",
     "ele2":null
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hot do you currently convert? Which libraries of the above mentioned did you try?

Comment: Current call is to org.json.XML.toJSONObject. (Note: I am asking on behalf of a developer who has not provided alternatives, and I'm looking to provide options to him. I don't have access to the code directly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no XML-to-JSON conversion library that will always give you exactly what you want. Generally, I would recommend doing an XML-to-XML pre-conversion using XSLT before you do the XML-to-JSON conversion - in this case the pre-conversion would eliminate the nilled elements.

If you want complete control over the generated JSON, try the mechanism in XSLT 3.0, where you first convert the XML to generic `<map>`, `<array>`, `<string>` and `<number>` elements, and then press the button to convert these to JSON syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I like the XSLT suggestion here. That may be a very simple approach.